# How to clear the controlled inputs in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

this is a sign-in page I created using React & styled components. I was trying to clear the input field values "onSubmit" but for some issue it does not work. Does anyone knows how should I clear the inputs with the button click ? Thank you!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Form,
  FormButton,
  FormContent,
  FormH1,
  FormInput,
  FormLabel,
  FormWrap,
  Icon,
  Text,
} from "./SigninElements";

const SignIn = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(email, password);
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <FormWrap>
        <Icon to="/">Sushi Finder</Icon>
        <FormContent>
          <Form action="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormH1>Sign in to your account</FormH1>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Email</FormLabel>
            <FormInput type="email" required onChange={handleEmailChange} />
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Password</FormLabel>
            <FormInput
              type="password"
              required
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
            />
            <FormButton type="submit">Continue</FormButton>
            <Text>Forgot Password</Text>
          </Form>
        </FormContent>
      </FormWrap>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Those aren't controlled components. Controlled components is where you directly pass in the value as a prop, thus explicitly **controlling** the value. Right now the value in the input is completely unaffected by what's in state. You'd have to give it like `value={email}` and then in that `FormInput` component pass that value onto the actual input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have ***are not*** controlled inputs, as Jayce444 points out. If you want to clear the inputs then you can do 1 of 2 things:

1. Actually make your inputs controlled by setting the `value` prop accordingly. Then the state updates in the submit handler will clear the state and be reflected in the inputs' values.

   ```
   <FormInput
     type="email"
     required
     onChange={handleEmailChange}
     value={email}
   />
   ...
   <FormInput
     type="password"
     required
     onChange={handlePasswordChange}
     value={password}
   />
   ```
2. Leave them uncontrolled and clear the inputs via the `onSubmit` event in the handler. Provide an `id` for each input to access in the submit handler and reset their values.

   ```
   const handleSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();

     console.log(email, password);
     setEmail("");
     setPassword("");

     e.target.email.value = "";
     e.target.password.value = "";
   };

   ...

   <FormInput
     type="email"
     required
     onChange={handleEmailChange}
     id="email"
   />
   ...
   <FormInput
     type="password"
     required
     onChange={handlePasswordChange}
     id="password"
   />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Its a uncontrolled component. That means single way approach you pass the value from input. But not possible to change the input via Dom.

> So better use controlled component `value={email}`. So this will reset
> the value via state.

And i have post solution for this uncontrolled component via key updated method.

**[Example Codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wescoff-6t013)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Form,
  FormButton,
  FormContent,
  FormH1,
  FormInput,
  FormLabel,
  FormWrap,
  Icon,
  Text,
} from "./SigninElements";

const keyGen = () => 'key'+Math.round(Math.random()*10000000000000);
const SignIn = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(keyGen());
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(email, password);
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setKey(keyGen())
  };
  return (
    <Container>
      <FormWrap>
        <Icon to="/">Sushi Finder</Icon>
        <FormContent key={key}>
          <Form action="POST" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormH1>Sign in to your account</FormH1>
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Email</FormLabel>
            <FormInput type="email" required onChange={handleEmailChange} />
            <FormLabel htmlFor="for">Password</FormLabel>
            <FormInput
              type="password"
              required
              onChange={handlePasswordChange}
            />
            <FormButton type="submit">Continue</FormButton>
            <Text>Forgot Password</Text>
          </Form>
        </FormContent>
      </FormWrap>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `useRef()` to control those input elements, which includes clearing them. Declare them for each input like so:

```
const input1 = React.useRef();
const input2 = React.useRef();
```

Then use the ref prop of the `FormInput`:

```
<FormInput
  ref={input1}
  type="password"
  required
  onChange={handlePasswordChange}
  id="password"
/>
```

And then you can clear them in your `handleSubmit` function like so:

```
input1.current.value = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of controlled components are that you can control them outside of the DOM. All you simply need to do is set the value state variable to null.

```
const [myValue, setMyValue] = React.useState(null)

const clearValue = () => {
  setMyValue(null)
}

const handleOnChange = (event) => {
  setMyValue(event.target.value)
}

return <>
  <FormInput
    onChange={handleOnChange}
    value={myValue}
  />
  <Button onClick={clearValue}>Clear</Button>
</>
```

Since the clear button calls `clearValue` on click and the `clearValue` sets `myValue` to null on click, this should clear the value of your input. Controlled components are driven by a variable, which is updated by what the user types. Uncontrolled components are only driven by what the user types.

To use a controlled component you are required to pass your state variable back to the component though.